# Simple tikz-timing example fails to compile with "TeX capacity exceeded"

Tags: tikz-timing

When trying to use the `timztimingtable` environment with MikTeX 2.9 (TikZ-Timing 0.7d), it fails with the following error message. However, using the plain `\timing` and `\texttiming` commands works fine. How can I fix this?

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\pgf@selectfontorig ->\pgf@selectfontorig 
                                          \nullfont 
l.6 T
     est & cccc\\
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
Foo \texttiming{cccc}      % This works

\begin{tikzpicture}
\timing {cccc};            % This also works
%\begin{tikztimingtable}   % This fails to compile
%Test & cccc\\
%\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't embed the `tikztimingtable` in a `tikzpicture`

Comment: Ah okay, that works... Don't know why I thought it should be that way.

Comment: The `tikztimingtable` is already a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Yes, that seems obvious now. But not when I wrote it. Writen an answer and I'll accept it. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently `tikztimingtable` doesn't like being called inside a `tikzpicture`, being a `tikzpicture` itself; the error is due to the mechanism TikZ/PGF uses for avoiding typesetting undesired things (that is, using `\nullfont` that has no character in it).

If you need it in a `tikzpicture`, then it's probably in the text for a node like in

```
\node at (0,0) {\begin{tikztimingtable}...\end{tikztimingtable}};
```

which works. But you can't use `tikztimingtable` at the top level in a `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
Foo \texttiming{cccc}      % This works

\begin{tikzpicture}
\timing {cccc};            % This also works
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikztimingtable}   % This is good
Test & cccc\\
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```